# laravel: can not accept post request without csrf

Tags: laravel, post, http-post, csrf

I have added into the exceptions:

```
    protected $except = [
        'pay/finish'
    ];
```

But still I am getting `MethodNotAllowedException`

Route is defined in `web.php`

```
Route::post('/pay/finish', ['as' => 'pay.finish', 'uses' => 'PaymentController@finish']);
```

The post request comes from another domain.

Comment: are you sure this route is defined as `Route::post` in your `web.php` ?

Comment: @Marcin yeah, it is defined

Comment: Are you sure this is coming in as post?

Comment: @apokryfos yeah, it is 100% post request

Comment: It looks like a 3rd party callback request. Those are typically not POST. If it's coming from a 3rd party source I'd confirm it with them to be sure. Also if you have any redirects happening e.g. a http to https rewrite this could also cause the request to change from POST to GET

Comment: @apokryfos yeah, it is 3rd party callback, but there is written that callback method will send POST request

Comment: Try using [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to make a POST request  to that URL yourself and see if you keep getting the same message just so you can eliminate some things.

Comment: @kerbholz ```https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection``` here it is written that it should be just url. The file is located in ```App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken```

Comment: I think the CSRF part here is a red herring. The `MethodNotAllowedException` would be thrown before a CSRF check is ever performed

Comment: is this coming from a 3rd party payment gateway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't normally get a `MethodNotAllowedException` from an invalid CSRF token. I normally get a 419 response from CSRF issues.

However, assuming the CSRF token is the problem you could move your route from `web.php` to `api.php`. Be aware this adds the prefix `api/` to the URL.

The middleware that checks the CSRF token is applied in your Kernel to all routes in `web.php` but not to those is `api.php`

You could verify whether the CSRF check is really the problem by looking in your `App\Http\Kernel` file and commenting out `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class` from:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

If your route then works it is CSRF and you can move the route to the API routes file and hit it at `api/pay/finish` with the api prefix.

If not then I suggest you look at what's calling your route and check the correct http method is being called. Is it definitely sending a `POST` request?
Do you have the `_method` input specified in your form that Laravel checks for `POST` requests to mutate them to `PUT` or `PATCH` for its edit routes?